# Regex how to add match for end of string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match strings that appear either beetween : and ; or between : and end of string

For example

text: **extract this**; text: **also extract this**

I'm using expression `(?<=:).*?(?=;)` which captures the first one but can't figure out how to add between : and end of string

Comment: whats your programming language?

Comment: `(?=;)` -> `(?=;|$)` or `(?![^;])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude the `;` from the match:

`(?<=:)[^;]+`

Details:

- `(?<=:)`: positive lookbehind, the one you are already using
- `[^;]+`: any character excepted a `;`, between one and unlimited repetitions

https://regex101.com/r/Ib3MQn/5

Edit: [VLAZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz) mentionned it in the comments below, please note that this regex will match multilines strings, ie this will match:

```
text: extract this; text: also extract this
and this will be extracted too
```

Comment: There is no need for the lookahead as the pattern is already going to avoid it. Although this *might* capture a newline as `[^;]` will match the end of line and continue: `a:b\nc` matches `b\nc`

Comment: Indeed you're right. Because the question is closed, i'm gonna delete this answer

Comment: Too late! Is there a way to delete it?

Comment: Not after it's accepted, I believe. Unless it gets unaccepted or a diamond mod deletes it but the latter happens only with rather big problems (e.g, plagiarism or spam). I'd suggest just editing the information to say how it behaves with multiline strings. If you wish, you can also give a multiline solution but it's not required.

Comment: You can omit this part `(?=;?)` as the `;` is optional in the pattern.